# Mysql incremental backup and point in time recovery

Tags: mysql, backup, shell-scripting

I have a requirement for doing Incremental backup of MySQL database. For which I'm writing a shell script using the concept of binary logs.

Now, the scenario is such that a full-backup will happen every alternate day and Incremental backup should be done in between.
Suppose full-backup happens on Monday and Wednesday, incremental backup should happen on Tuesday.
For point in time recovery, I'm using **`mysqlbinlog --starttime --stoptime binary-logs > backup.sql`**
In the shell script I need to use starttime and log position of the previous full-backup to specify the log files in the statement, how can I retrieve this in a shell script and record the changes done during that time.
Is there anyway I can do this, please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Xtrabackup utility for mysql incremental backup they have shell script also you have to modify script according to your need.

Comment: I honestly can't recommend it enough to just learn xtrabackup vs writing it on your own

Comment: I'm interested in a shell script, can anyone help me.

Comment: From here you can check Shell Script https://gist.github.com/abhishekamralkar/4149641